# Disable Contacts sync does not work

Tags: contacts, sync, google-pixel, android-10, xprivacy

I have found that with my Pixel 4XL (or maybe it's Android 10) **disabling Contacts syncing NO LONGER WORKS!** With my older Pixel 2 it did work, and I would manually trigger a Contacts or Calendar sync when I wanted to. I have checked and double-checked all the settings (see below)... but it still syncs without me triggering a sync.

The settings I make are as follows ... Via Settings -> Accounts
At the bottom of the main accounts page, there is a toggle named "**Automatically sync data**" with the text "Let apps sync data automatically". If this "Automatically sync data" toggle is **ON** and you then select your GMail account, and press the "**Account sync**" button, you are able to edit the(Google) apps you don't want to auto-sync (i.e. turn sync OFF). I do this (I switch all Google apps to off), and return to my GMail account page. I then see "**Sync OFF for all items**" in grey text under the "Account Sync" button (my upper case for OFF above).
I then go back up to a higher level .. that is back to the main accounts page. The toggle "Automatically sync data" is still ON of course, and the grey text under it says "**Let apps sync data automatically**".
I don't want this to happen, so I now set this "**Automatically sync data**" toggle to **OFF**.
Here's the problem: after making this last change (i.e. "Automatically sync data" toggle to OFF), when I select my GMail account again, I now see "**Sync ON for all items**" in grey text under the "Account sync" button(my upper case for ON above)!!  This is completely contradictory! How can it be that after first disabling auto-sync on all the Google apps and then switching off "Automatically sync data" Google signals "Sync on for all items" ?!?

And here's the bigger problem: the above message is correct. Because if I leave the settings as above the Contacts does indeed continue periodically auto-syncing. (I know this because if I delete my contacts in the Google Contacts app in the cloud after a short period all the contacts on my phone disappear too!).

I have tried removing my Google account and adding it again, but without success.
It seems to me that this is either (a) a bug in the "Automatically sync data" implementation .. OR .. (b) a deliberate implementation of Google to fool people that their data is NOT being synced. I have also tried all sorts of variations and checked Google account settings in the cloud too (not much there!), all to no avail.
It seems I cannot now disable auto-syncing of Contacts ...
If somebody thinks I'm missing something help would be appreciated?

Comment: I am pretty sure this is just another Google scam .. because they don't want people to disable contact syncing. I posted this same message over on a Google support site, and after receiving a few feeble replies from a "Platinium" expert my post was disabled and labelled "This question is locked and replying has been disabled" .
Here is that post:
[Disable contacts sync does not work](http://support.google.com/pixelphone/thread/39844583?hl=en)
I can confirm that everything I describe is still verifiable .. I test every week or so!

Comment: Go to Settings > Apps > See all apps > ⋮ > Show system > Search > Google Contacts Sync > Disable

Comment: Although it seems that the Google Contacts Sync app may not be there on Android 13 any more, so this might not work for Android 13+

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue and am happy that I'm not the only one.

Under **Settings > Google > Account Services > Contacts sync** you will find two Options - **Automatically sync Google contacts** and **Back up & sync device contacts** - to disable. I will test this the next few days and report back if it didn't do the trick.
I guess they have moved this option and replaced it with a wired design.

Comment: I had these settings already unchecked on Android 10, but the contacts of unsynced accounts still show up.